# Make not successful building VIC on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, zip

I am trying to build Variable Infiltration Capacity microscale hydrologic model — i.e VIC software is to be made executable.

I have extracted the zip file and then on the terminal I wrote `make` to have an executable file for the software to run.
The link from where I downloaded the zip file is https://github.com/UW-Hydro/VIC (from the download Zip option). The folder contains many C files and a makefile.
I have tried building on both Windows and Linux but could not get the result. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to run `make` when in the `src` folder, too.

Comment: All I can tell you is that it compiled cleanly out of the box for me on Mac OS X 10.9.3 with GCC (actually Clang) `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`.  I would expect it to compile equally as easily on Linux.  I reserve judgement on how it would compile on Windows.  At the very least, you need to show how you ran `make` on Linux and what the errors are.

Comment: i am getting the error as :There is no internal or external command found as make in windows though i have set correct environment variables. also in ubuntu m getting the same error as SRCS,CC etc command not found. The way i did was I extracted the zip file and then through terminal i moved to the directory and types ./Makefile. (ubuntu). Same with the windows.